# Whenever I try to import the arch_model module, I receive the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arch'

Tags: arch

I am encountering an issue with the arch library in Python. Whenever I try to import the arch_model module, I receive the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arch'

Here are the details of my setup:

- Python version: 3.11.3
- Operating system: MAC Ventura 13.4.1

I have already attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- Verified that the arch library is installed using pip list.
- Checked the installed versions of arch using pip show arch.
- Tried reinstalling arch using `pip install --force-reinstall arch`.
- Confirmed that I am working within the correct virtual environment.

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to resolve the issue.How to fix this problem?

I have tried multiple commands to install arch, including:

```
pip install arch
pip install git+https://github.com/bashtage/arch.git
pip install --force-reinstall statsmodels arch
pip install statsmodels arch
```

even:

```
pip install arch==6.0
```

Currently, these are the installed libraries in my virtual environment:

```
appnope 0.1.3
arch 6.0.0
asttokens 2.2.1
backcall 0.2.0
decorator 5.1.1
executing 1.2.0
ipython 8.14.0
jedi 0.18.2
matplotlib-inline 0.1.6
numpy 1.25.0
packaging 23.1
pandas 2.0.3
parso 0.8.3
patsy 0.5.3
pexpect 4.8.0
pickleshare 0.7.5
pip 23.1.2
prompt-toolkit 3.0.38
ptyprocess 0.7.0
pure-eval 0.2.2
Pygments 2.15.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz 2023.3
scipy 1.11.1
setuptools 67.8.0
six 1.16.0
stack-data 0.6.2
statsmodels 0.14.0
traitlets 5.9.0
tzdata 2023.3
var 2023.6.2
wcwidth 0.2.6
wheel 0.38.4
```

Comment: It might be useful to tell what actually happens when you try to install it

Comment: Are you running this from a command line?  Are you sure your `pip` is for the same version of Python you are running?  MacOS ships with Python 2 and Python 3, and many people use `brew` to install a 3rd.  Your pip must match.  Does `python -m pip install arch` help?

Comment: Helllo, I doesn't work...
Error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/4n/50zl6jxd08b3b_s6930jjjsh0000gn/T/ipykernel_40983/3697679417.py in <module>
---> 10 import arch
     11 from arch import arch_model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arch'

Comment: what happens when I tried to install it:

(mis_series) me@me-MacBook-Pro ~ % python -m pip install arch

Requirement already satisfied: arch in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/mis_series/lib/python3.11/site-packages (6.0.0)

...

(mis_series) me@me-MacBook-Pro ~ %